# How to control the font in a form's text input field

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a `<form>` with several text input fields like so:

```
<input id="reg" type="text" name="reg" style="width: 200px;" class="eztext">
```

in my `<script>` section just before `</body>` I have code to select a font for the all these fields:

```
        var el = document.getElementsByClassName("eztext")

        for (var i = 0; i < el.length; i++)
        {
            el[i].style.fontSize = "30px";
            el[i].style.backgroundColor = "#00ff00"; // bright green background as diagnostic
        }
```

When I run this for the first time in a browser with a cleared cache, the form looks exactly as expected with a bright green background and if I enter text in the box then it appears with a big 30px font... However, if I have used the form several times before then it appears the browser has remembered several previous entries, i.e. I see some previously entered text already in the form and if I click on the text field I see a menu listing a variety of previously entered strings.

My problem is that both the background color and the font are clearly being set by some other system, the font is not size 30 and the background is not green. Unfortunately, I do not know what thing is controlling the style of the font. I can't find anything in the documentation about the `<input>` tag.

Comment: Chrome for instance automatically saves input field values if it recognizes them, but it should not affect the "styling". But why aren't you doing normal CSS styling? You have the selectors available. You're basically over complicating the issue with unnecessary JavaScript it looks like.

Comment: is the font size and color of the actual input not correct anymore, or is the auto fill box that opens underneath the problem?

Comment: @Martin: Actually in the "30px" is a parameter that varies according to screen size - I just put 30px here for simplicity.

Comment: Still probably more a case for using CSS variables nevertheless.

Comment: @Ramon de Vries: when I go to the page (for the second time) the text that is in the text field is small (<30px) and against a pale blue background. If I click in the text field the font immediately changes to the correct (30px) size but the background remains pale blue! Underneath the field is now a list of old text strings in a small black font against a white background.

Comment: okay, so its the browsers autofill that is messing the input up, take a look here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/change-autocomplete-styles-webkit-browsers/ . and about the list of old text strings, yes that is normal behaviour and i wouldn't change that if i were you.

Comment: @Ramon de Vries: I think you have correctly diagnosed the problem - thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browsers save previous input values for the user out of convenience. However, this should not affect the styling of the element(s) at all.

First check that you do not have CSS that gets overwritten somehow.

1. Order of CSS, both included and inline CSS.
2. The `!important` property.

You also seem to be using unnecessary JavaScript to apply your style(s). Is there any deeper meaning to why you're using JavaScript the way you are? You have the selectors available to you to simply go with a normal CSS solution.

As a last resort, you could go for disabling the autocomplete feature, but that should be your last resort, as it is a quality of life improvement for the user to have that available to them. There are multiple ways to do this, the most simple one would be:

```
<input id="reg" type="text" name="reg" style="width: 200px;" class="eztext" autocomplete="off">
```

Or for the entire form:

```
<form autocomplete="off" action="...">
```

More about disabling input fields [here](https://www.scotsscripts.com/blog/html-css-trick-how-to-turn-off-auto-complete.html).

If it's about the background styling of the input fields themselves entirely, you can use `-webkit` CSS properties to get your desired styles.

More about that [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/change-autocomplete-styles-webkit-browsers/).

> Provided by @ Ramon de Vries in the comment section